# Subtraction in bare perturbation theory on Peskin's book

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

On chapter 7 of their book on QFT, Peskin and Schroeder derive the vacuum polarization correction to the photon propagator in bare renormalization theory. On page 247, they state that to leading order in $\alpha$, $\Pi(p)=\Pi_2(p)$. This is obviously simply the definition of $\Pi_2(p)$, the one loop correction to the transverse part of the propagator. The problem is that they imediately go on to say

> The amplitude for the process will then involve the quantity
>
> $$ \frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}\frac{e_0^2}{1-\Pi(q^2)}\underset{\mathcal{O}(\alpha)}{=}\frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2}\frac{e^2}{1-[\Pi_2(q^2)-\Pi_2(0)]} $$
>
> (Swapping $e^2$ for $e_0^2$ does not matter to lowest order.)

**which I do not understand: where did the $\Pi_2(0)$ come from?** In fact, this is clearly the actual *renormalization* part, and what they are doing is to subtract the infinite part of $\Pi_2$ and fix the residue of the propagator at $1$ -- but it looks as if I'm missing something since it is not clear from the book at all.

The point is that this is not clear in the text and I cannot make sense of the math without this external input. How does the equality above hold to lowest order and in what sense? What do the authors mean with *their* presented line of thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part follows from the condition that the residue at the pole should be $-i$ (or one, depends if you include the $i$ in the numerator of the propagator). In fact it's easy to see that defining $$\Pi(q^2) = \Pi_2(q^2)-\Pi_2(0)$$ one directly gets that, at the pole $$q^2=0 \to \Pi(0)=0$$ and so that the residue at the pole is $$\underset{q^2=0}{\text{Res}}\,D_{\mu\nu}(q^2) = \lim_{q^2\to0}q^2\frac{-i}{q^2}\frac{1}{1-\Pi(q^2)} = -i\frac{1}{1-\Pi(0)} = -i$$

If one didn't subtract $\Pi_2(0)$ there wouldn't be any
certainty that $\Pi_2(0)=0$. And we wouldn't even be able to impose it since $\Pi_2(q^2)$ is what it is and comes out directly from the calculation of the vacuum polarization.

Moreover, this has to be true at all orders in perturbation theory.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So, I actually understand and express the idea of your answer in the question, but this does not seem to be what the authors meant, unless if with a tremendous language abuse and sloppiness. They make this passage as if it was a direct consequence of the lowest order approximation and don't relate it to a renormalization condition at all.

Comment: They are taking as given the fact that $\Pi(q^2)=0$ at all orders, and this is due to the physical requirement of the residue at the pole. Then when going to lowest order they won't get only $\Pi_2(q^2)$ but the rescaled quantity.

Comment: In fact they gave the renormalization condition before, just after the formula (7.75)